# Is it possible to use wget for copying files in my own system?

Tags: command-line, wget

I want to move/copy large size of files in my own system, and I want to use `wget` command with its `-c` switch to having a resumable transferring. The copy(`cp`) or move(`mv`) commands doesn't provide this option for me.

Is it possible to use `wget` to copy these files from one directory to another directory in my own system?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, but you need a web server set up to serve the files you need to copy.

try something like this. On a terminal, start a simple web server:

```
cd /etc/
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

then open another terminal and do:

```
wget http://localhost:8000/passwd
```

the passwd file will be downloaded to your current directory. You're in effect copying it from /etc/ to your home directory.

I'm not sure why you want to do this but yes, in principle, as you can see, it is possible.

Comment: doesnt work in 2018

Comment: @donbright you can try `python3 -m http.server` instead, as this command is for Python 2. If you're receiving an error, you should post the error so others can help.

Comment: I launched the server as `root` from the root directory so I could easily target files system-wide.

Comment: Docker experiments in my case.

Comment: yup this is fabulous for docker....i.e. not using this in a RUN command so it can be combined with other steps which can't be done with the COPY command

Answer (score 18):

It would probably make more sense to use `rsync` instead. For example:

```
rsync -aP /source ~/destination
```

The `-P` or `--partial` flag prevents incomplete files from being deleted if there is an interruption. If you run the same command again, any incomplete transfer will be resumed.

This way, no need to bother with a local web server, which you would need for `wget`.

Answer (score 9):

While I strongly recommend `rsync`, you can use `curl` without running an HTTP server:

```
curl -O -C - file:///path/to/some/file
```

`curl` is different from `wget`, but is just as, if not more, powerful. It's always handy to have on any system.

From [`man curl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/curl.1.html):

```
   -C, --continue-at <offset>
          Continue/Resume  a  previous  file transfer at the given offset.
          Use  "-C  -" to tell curl to automatically find out where/how to
          resume the transfer
   -O, --remote-name
          Write  output to a local file named like the remote file we get.
```

Answer (score 3):

`lftp` can handle local file systems without need for a server.

> **`lftp`** - Sophisticated file transfer program
>
> **lftp** can handle several file access methods - ftp, ftps, http, https, hftp, fish, sftp and file (https and ftps are  only  available  when lftp is compiled with GNU TLS or OpenSSL library).
>
> Besides FTP-like protocols, lftp has support for BitTorrent protocol as `torrent' command. Seeding is also supported.

**Reference:** [`man lftp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/lftp.1.html)

- To copy a sinlge file: (use `mget` for multiple files or with `*` joker)

  ```
    lftp -c "get -c file:///<absolute-path-to-file>"
  ```
- To copy a folder:

  ```
    lftp -c "mirror -c file:///<absolute-path-to-directory>"
  ```

First `-c` for *command*, second `-c` for *continue* whenever possible.

For space, It does work for me either `\`  like shell or `%20` like web URL.

Answer (score 1):

it's possible. You need to have a web server like apache or nginx. 
if it's apache, to copy file you can do this

`wget http://localhost/path/to/file/starting/from/var/www/` because de home directory to the apache server is /var/www

Answer (score 1):

Another way using, using `dd`:

1. Check destination file size using `stat` or `ls -l` command
2. Copy using:

   ```
   dd if=<source-file-path> iflag=skip_bytes skip=<dest-file-size> oflag=seek_bytes seek=<dest-file-size> of=<dest-file-path>
   ```

Example:

```
$ ls -l /home/user/u1404_64_d.iso
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 147186688 Jan  8 17:01 /home/user/u1404_64_d.iso

$ dd if=/boot/grml/u1404_64_d.iso \
  iflag=skip_bytes skip=147186688 oflag=seek_bytes seek=147186688 \
  of=/home/user/u1404_64_d.iso
1686798+0 records in
1686798+0 records out
863640576 bytes (864 MB) copied, 15.1992 s, 56.8 MB/s

$ md5sum /boot/grml/u1404_64_d.iso /home/user/u1404_64_d.iso
dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153  /boot/grml/u1404_64_d.iso
dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153  /home/user/u1404_64_d.iso
```

It could be harmful as it can overwrite file without check, here a better function to check for hash before continue:

```
ddc () {

    # enable hash check, need much time to read both files
    hashcheck=true

    # check destination folder existance or assume it's a file name
    if [ -d "$2" ]
    then
        ofpath="$2/`basename \"$1\"`"
    else
        ofpath="$2"
    fi

    # check destination file existance
    if [ ! -f "$ofpath" ]
    then
        a="n"
    else
        ofsize=`stat -c "%s" "$ofpath"`


        # calculate hash
        if [ $hashcheck ]
        then 
            ifhash=`dd if="$1" iflag=count_bytes count=$ofsize 2>/dev/null | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'`
            #ifhash=`head -c $ofsize "$1" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'`
            ofhash=`md5sum "$ofpath" | awk '{print $1}'`

            # check hash before cont.
            if [ $ifhash == $ofhash ]
            then
                a="y"
            else
                echo -e "Files MD5 mismatch do you want to continue:\n(Y) Continue copy, (N) Start over, (Other) Cancel"
                read a
            fi
        else
            a="y"
        fi
    fi

    case $a in
    [yY])
        echo -e "Continue...\ncopy $1 to $ofpath"
        dd if="$1" iflag=skip_bytes skip=$ofsize oflag=seek_bytes seek=$ofsize of="$ofpath"
        ;;
    [nN])
        echo -e "Start over...\ncopy $1 to $ofpath"
        dd if="$1" of="$ofpath"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Cancelled!"
        ;;
    esac

}
```

Use:

```
ddc <source-file> <destination-file-or-folder>
```

Example:

```
$ ls -l /home/user/u1404_64_d.iso
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 241370112 Jan  8 17:09 /home/user/u1404_64_d.iso

$ ddc /boot/grml/u1404_64_d.iso /home/user/u1404_64_d2.iso
Continue...copy /boot/grml/u1404_64_d.iso to /home/user/u1404_64_d.iso
1502846+0 records in
1502846+0 records out
769457152 bytes (769 MB) copied, 13.0472 s, 59.0 MB/s
```

Answer (score 1):

Still another way:

1. Get remaining size to copy

   ```
   echo `stat -c "%s" <source-file>`-`stat -c "%s" <destination-file>` | bc
   ```
2. Redirect output of `tail`

   ```
   tail -c <remaining-size> <source-file> >> <destination-file>
   ```

Example:

```
$ echo `stat -c "%s" /boot/grml/u1404_64_d.iso`-`stat -c "%s" /home/user/u1404_64_d.iso` | bc
433049600

$ tail -c 433049600 /boot/grml/u1404_64_d.iso >> /home/user/u1404_64_d.iso

$ md5sum /boot/grml/u1404_64_d.iso /home/user/u1404_64_d.iso
dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153  /boot/grml/u1404_64_d.iso
dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153  /home/user/u1404_64_d.iso
```

Answer (score 1):

Since time seems to be an issue for you - another approach is to use the command `split` to break a large file into smaller pieces, e.g.,
`split -b 1024m BIGFILE PIECES`
to create 1 GByte pieces named PIECESaa PIECESab ... PIECESzz

Once these are created you would use something like
`cat PIECES?? >/some/where/else/BIGFILE` to reconstruct BIGFILE, or again, because of your time concerns:

```
mkdir done
>/somewhere/else/BIGFILE
for piece in PIECES??
do
    cat $piece >>/some/where/else/BIGFILE
    status=$?
    if [[ $status -eq 0 ]]
    then
        mv $piece done
    fi
done
```

If the 'copy' fails you can move the files from ./done back to . and try again once the time issue is resolved. - See this as a alternative when wget is not possible. It is something I have used over the years when copying to a remote location and something like 'plain ftp' is the only transport possible - for the pieces.